# How can I join sets in Zimpl?

Tags: scip

I have two parameters read from file, of `m*n` (Months * Nights) dimension:
`A[m,n]` and `B[m,n]`

How can I make a set / parameter from these two parameters so that the new set will have the same indices `m*n`, and elements combined as sets with an extra zero between?

For example, let's say `A["D", 5] = 35, B["D", 5] = 2` ,
I want to have `C["D", 5] = {35, 0, 2}`

Is this possible?

ps: I want to use it in the objective min/max, I tried to just use

```
{A[a,b], 0, B[a,b]}[index]
```

but failed, so I am trying to get a pre-defined sets to use instead.

Comment: Hard to understand what you want to do. Can you state the mathematical term of your objective function that you're trying to implement?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. My objective function is a bit complicated, I want to use something like `sum <m,n> in Months*Nights: difference[m,n] * C[m,n][sgn(difference[m,n] + 1]`, where difference is some integer variables counted from another two variables. @ddotsdot

Comment: `minimize abc: sum <m,n> in Months*Nights: difference[m,n] * C[m,n][sgn(difference[m,n]) + 1]` -- forgot a `)`. I tried many times failed to use `if then` or `with variableA > variableB`  inside objective, thus came up this method.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this:

```
set C[<m,n> in Months*Nights] := {A[m,n], 0, B[m,n]} ;
```

And I can refer them in this way:

```
ord(C[m,n],3,1)
```

Where `3` refer to `B[m,n]`, and `1` is a placeholder for the third parameter of `ord` function.